# Give the example of compact set with infinite countable derived set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples

Can anyone give me an example of compact set of which the derived set is infinitely countable set??

thks in advance, I have no idea about this .

Comment: The "derived set" is the set of accumulation points within the given set?  If so, just take $[0,1]\subset \mathbb R$.

Comment: @lulu In this case the derived set is equal to $[0,1]$, which is uncountable.

Comment: @MartinSleziak.  Ah!  Dangers of hasty reading.  Am I right about the definition?

Comment: @lulu It is up to OP to clarify this, but I think the common meaning is the set of all limit points: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_%28mathematics%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, put $A:=\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},...\}$.

Then the set $B:=\{0\}\cup\bigcup_n \left(\frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^n} A\right)$ is compact (closed and bounded) and has derived set $B'=\{0\}\cup \{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},...\}$.